# Installing Pycurl on CentOS?

Tags: python, linux, curl, centos, pycurl

I'm finding it to install **pycurl** on **CentOS 5** quite the mission impossible.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

Some help would be beyond amazing. :|

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I was just having this issue and the solution was to add the following soft link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.1.0 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

This is for libcurl 7.19.

The problem appears to be that pycurl is looking for the libcurl so in a different location than where it gets installed on CentOS.

This works when installing pycurl manually, such as when are using a python version other than 2.4, which is probably most of today's installs. I assume the pycurl centos rpm handles that, but that works for 2.4 only.

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 13 python-pycurl would be the package you were looking for. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the libcurl libraries, which you can install like this:

```
sudo yum install libcurl
```

After that, it may be a good idea to refresh your pycurl install, by doing the following:

```
sudo easy_install pycurl
```

If that gives you the error "command not found" (I don't know if CentOS'es built-in version of Python includes SetupTools a/k/a/ easy_install), then you need the SetupTools first and then run the easy_install command above:

```
sudo yum install python-setuptools
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yum output:
No package libcurl available.
Nothing to do.